# How to match an exact match in a list python

Tags: python, list

How can I check to see if an exact match of B appears in A in the same consecutive order? In the below example `99, 3, 2` are in A in that exact way :

```
A =  [0, 3, 123, 0, 99, 3, 2, 1, 2, 33, 1, 76]

B =  [99, 3, 2]
```

An example of A which would fail is :

```
A = [0, 321, 99, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]
```

As `99, 3, 2` elements do not appear consecutively.

I have tried doing :

```
if B in A:
   print("yes")
else:
   print("NO")
```

This fails.

Thank you all,
Jemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def consecutive_in(B,A):
    return B in (A[i:i+len(B)] for i in range(len(A)))
```

Comment: Thank you fab - could you kindly talk me through:
return B in (A[i:i+len(B)] for i in range(len(A)))
especially the i:i+len(B)

I understand len for lenghth but the rest just jumbled in my head

Comment: @NoobyD try to run "print([A[i:i+len(B)] for i in range(len(A))])"

Comment: A[i:i+len(B)] means a sub-list of A starting from A[i] with length len(B)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) with generator expression that compares all slices of length `b` with `b`:

```
>>> a = [0, 3, 123, 0, 99, 3, 2, 1, 2, 33, 1, 76]
>>> b = [99, 3, 2]
>>> any(b == a[i:i+len(b)] for i in range(len(a) - len(b) + 1))
True
>>> a = [0, 321, 99, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]
>>> any(b == a[i:i+len(b)] for i in range(len(a) - len(b) + 1))
False
```

`range(len(a) - len(b) + 1)` returns all the possible starting locations of subsequences with same length as `b`. `b == a[i:i+len(b)]` creates a list of length `b` starting from index `i` and compares it with `b` resulting to a boolean value. `any` will return `True` if any of the generated boolean values is `True` or `False` in case all the values are `False`.